# Cardinality of the intersection between an open set and an affine linear subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove the following:

Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$ be an affine linear subspace with $\dim(S) \geq 1$, and $A = (0,1)^N \subset \mathbb{R}^N$.
Suppose that there exists a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$ such that $x \in S$ and $x \in A$. Then $S \cap A$ has infinite elements.

I think that the first step to prove the previous is to consider a sphere $B(x,r)$ centered in $x$ with radius $r > 0$ such that $B(x,r) \subset A$, knowing that $B(x,r)$ always exists since $A$ is open.

Then? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should start by taking an open ball $B_x(ε)$ around $x$ contained in $A$. Then take another point $y$ from $B∩S$.

This is possible because $S$ has dimension greater $0$, i.e. there is a basis of the associated vector space with at least one element $e_1$ which gives $y := x + \tfrac{ε}{2\lVert e_1\rVert}e_1$ lying in $B_x(ε)∩S$ as $ \lVert x - y\rVert = \tfracε2 < ε$.

Now you have $$∀t\in(0,1)\colon x + (y-x)t \in S∩A,$$
because balls are convex and $S$ is affine. Thus you have an injection $t ↦ x + (y-x)t$ from a non-empty real interval into your set $S∩A$. This shows that the cardinality of $S∩A$ is at least the cardinality of $ℝ$. But $S∩A ⊂ ℝ^N$, so it can not be greater, i.e. $S∩A$ and $ℝ$ have the same cardinality

Comment: How can I be sure that I can take $y \in B \cup S$?

Comment: @the_candyman: I added a proof for that.